# Using DOM and nothing is appearing

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to use arrays and the DOM to display quotes, which are stored in an array, to the screen.  I believe I am currently using the document object model in one instance, because I am getting output.  In the other instance though, I am unable to get anything to display on the screen (the date and the quote of the day are not displaying on the screen).

I have looked and looked to try and find out what I am doing wrong, but with no success.  This is for an assignment and I am required to use the DOM.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JSJQ Assignment 4 - Arrays / Date Starter File</title>

<style>
    body{
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    form{
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
</style>

<script>

    //************************************************************
    // 1: define variables for today's date,
    //************************************************************
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var year = today.getFullYear();

    //************************************************************
    // 2: define an array to hold the day names 
    //************************************************************
    var monthArray = new Array();

    monthArray[0] = "January";
    monthArray[1] = "February";
    monthArray[2] = "March";
    monthArray[3] = "April";
    monthArray[4] = "May";
    monthArray[5] = "June";
    monthArray[6] = "July";
    monthArray[7] = "August";
    monthArray[8] = "September";
    monthArray[9] = "October";
    monthArray[10] = "November";
    monthArray[11] = "December";

    var dayArray = new Array();

    dayArray[0] = "Monday";
    dayArray[1] = "Tuesday";
    dayArray[2] = "Wednesday";
    dayArray[3] = "Thursday";
    dayArray[4] = "Friday";
    dayArray[5] = "Saturday";
    dayArray[6] = "Sunday";


    //************************************************************
    // 3: define an array to hold the daily quotes
    //************************************************************

    var quoteArray = new Array();

    quoteArray[0] = "Ability is nothing without opportunity - Napoleon Bonaparte";
    quoteArray[1] = "Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg";
    quoteArray[2] = "Believe you can and you're halfway there - Theodore Roosevelt";
    quoteArray[3] = "A place for everything, everything in its place - Benjamin Franklin";
    quoteArray[4] = "Don't let the fear of striking out hold you back - Babe Ruth";
    quoteArray[5] = "We can't help everyone, but everyone can help someone - Ronald Reagan";
    quoteArray[6] = "With self-discipline most anything is possible - Theodore Roosevelt";


    //************************************************************
    // 4:  loop through all of the quotes
    //    and write the quotes to the page. Use DOM methods or innerHTML
    //    to write to the page.
    //************************************************************
    function allQuotes() {

        var allQuotes = document.getElementById('quotes');

        for (var i = 0; i < quoteArray.length; i++) {

            var text = document.createTextNode(quoteArray[i]);
            var br = document.createElement('br');

            allQuotes.appendChild(text);
            allQuotes.appendChild(br);
        }

        quoteOfTheDay();
    }

    //************************************************************
    // 5: create a window.onload function to format and display
    //    the current day name.
    //
    //    Display the quote for the day.
    //
    //    
    //************************************************************

    function quoteOfTheDay() {
        document.getElementById('quote_of_the_day').firstChild.nodeValue = quoteArray[today.getDay()-1];

        document.getElementById('date').firstChild.nodeValue = dayArray[day] + ", " + monthArray[month] + day + ", " + year;
    }

    window.onload = allQuotes;

</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Quote of the Day</h1>
<p id="quote_of_the_day"></p>
<p id="date"></p>

<h2>All the quotes:</h2>
<p id="quotes"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just copied your code , saved it and opened the HTML file in Chrome. I can see all quotes, the only thing missing is Quote of the day

Comment: @Satya. I cannot find a starting 'body' tag.

Comment: @MatthewSpire put your script after the body Section ends it works. try please and say me what happend.

Comment: @MatthewSpire i edit your question use this in the same way?

Comment: i can understand why this happens in your browser? Don worry i ll do it wait i m seeing again :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some logical mistakes in your scripts Code. Use this method

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title>JSJQ Assignment 4 - Arrays / Date Starter File</title>
<body>
<h1>Quote of the Day</h1>
<p id="quote_of_the_day"></p>
<p id="date"></p>
<h2>All the quotes:</h2>
<p id="quotes"></p>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Script**

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();

//************************************************************
// 2: define an array to hold the day names 
//************************************************************
var monthArray = new Array();

monthArray[0] = "January";
monthArray[1] = "February";
monthArray[2] = "March";
monthArray[3] = "April";
monthArray[4] = "May";
monthArray[5] = "June";
monthArray[6] = "July";
monthArray[7] = "August";
monthArray[8] = "September";
monthArray[9] = "October";
monthArray[10] = "November";
monthArray[11] = "December";

var dayArray = new Array();

dayArray[0] = "Monday";
dayArray[1] = "Tuesday";
dayArray[2] = "Wednesday";
dayArray[3] = "Thursday";
dayArray[4] = "Friday";
dayArray[5] = "Saturday";
dayArray[6] = "Sunday";


//************************************************************
// 3: define an array to hold the daily quotes
//************************************************************

var quoteArray = new Array();

quoteArray[0] = "Ability is nothing without opportunity - Napoleon Bonaparte";
quoteArray[1] = "Nothing happens unless first we dream - Carl Sandburg";
quoteArray[2] = "Believe you can and you're halfway there - Theodore Roosevelt";
quoteArray[3] = "A place for everything, everything in its place - Benjamin Franklin";
quoteArray[4] = "Don't let the fear of striking out hold you back - Babe Ruth";
quoteArray[5] = "We can't help everyone, but everyone can help someone - Ronald Reagan";
quoteArray[6] = "With self-discipline most anything is possible - Theodore Roosevelt";


//************************************************************
// 4:  loop through all of the quotes
//    and write the quotes to the page. Use DOM methods or innerHTML
//    to write to the page.
//************************************************************
function allQuotes() {

    var allQuotes = document.getElementById('quotes');

    for (var i = 0; i < quoteArray.length; i++) {

        var text = document.createTextNode(quoteArray[i]);

        var br = document.createElement('br');
    allQuotes.appendChild(text);
        allQuotes.appendChild(br);

    }
   quoteOfTheDay();
}

//************************************************************
// 5: create a window.onload function to format and display
//    the current day name.
//
//    Display the quote for the day.
//
//    
//************************************************************

function quoteOfTheDay() {

     document.getElementById('quote_of_the_day').firstChild.nodeValue = quoteArray[today.getDay()-1];

    document.getElementById('date').firstChild.nodeValue = dayArray[day] + ", " + monthArray[month] + day + ", " + year; }


window.onload = allQuotes;
```

Comment: I cannot use innerHTML to write to the page, otherwise I would have.  I am required to use firstChild.nodeValue for the quote of the day and the date.

Comment: My browser is still not showing anything besides the header text.  Do you have any idea why that might be occurring?  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Which bowser you are using ? Chrome or fire fox

Comment: Chrome, but I just fixed it to show window.onload = allQuotes; but I'm still not getting the quote of the day or the current date.  I will post my latest edited code.  One moment please.

Comment: I just edited to show the most recent version of my code.  If I missed one of your corrections, then I apologize.

Comment: @MatthewSpire once you try with the Dummy Content just Add any dummy content in you quotes of the day and date section and then run and say me what happened after that you remove your dummy contents in html part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109294/discussion-between-matthewspire-and-akhilesh-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
window.onload = quoteOfTheDay;
window.onload = allQuotes;
```

only `allQuotes` will run when the window finishes loading because you can only assign one value to `window.onload`. If you want both to be called on window load wrap them in a function and assign it to window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
    quoteOfTheDay();
    allQuotes();
};
```

Also you try to get the first child of `quote_of_the_day` and `date` but they have no children. You could either put content in them like a space or something or just set the entire contents and not the value of a child node.

Comment: The 'onload' = functions can be in series and still work, but your correct in that you cannot make more than one use of the 'onload' fuction within the body tag. You can only use the term 'onload' once.

Comment: I made the correction, but now nothing is displaying when I test.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is missing that you should be seeing on your browser. Please be specific. So far we have just been fixing "bugs'.

Comment: After the suggested correction, only the header text is appearing.  I.e.

Quote of the Day

All the quotes:

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a starting body tag and unless you intentionally missed them, your code should end with:

```
</body>
</html>
```

I would fix this issue first and see if it helps.

Comment: can you explain this ? Did you try this in your browser or else anywhere?

Comment: @AkhileshSingh. If these closing tags are missing, the code will work by accident, if at all. I see the opening tags but I did not see these closing tags in the code.

Comment: The closing tags MUST be there, or the code and DOM structure is incomplete.

Comment: *The closing tags MUST be there*. This is incorrect. The browser will patch that up.

Comment: I apologize for accidentally not including them in my initial post, but the closing tags are there.

Comment: I now see them using my Chrome developers plugin. It looked good before you added the tags, but Chrome covers up a lot of quirks. By adding those tags you should get a correct display on any browser. (Except ancient IE versions)

Comment: Yes, but the required content is still not displaying despite the corrections (I'm also using the latest version of Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

replace your quoteOfTheDay function with

```
 function quoteOfTheDay() {
                    document.getElementById('quote_of_the_day').firstChild.nodeValue = quoteArray[today.getDay() - 1];
       // document.getElementById('date').firstChild.nodeValue = dayArray[day] + ", " + monthArray[month] + day + ", " + year;
    }
```

And add a dummy element inside `quote_of_the_day` e.g.

```
<p id="quote_of_the_day"><span></span></p>
```

, as the code is looking for a **child element** of **quote_of_the_day** but it is empty, so the code is failing.